# calculate Earth coordinates having meters distance from another point in node.js/Javascript

Tags: node.js, coordinates

I am working on javascript function on calculating the earth coordinates of a beacon positioned from a particular point. I know the coordinates of the point and the distance of the beacon from that particular point. Is there any way/packages to calculate the coordinates of the beacon in Node.js/Javascript

Comment: How accurate does it have to be? Calculating such coordinates to give you a location that’s accurate to the nearest millimetre is really difficult, since the Earth is not an exact geometric ideal.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.